# Gerrit email notification for push to master branch

Tags: git, gerrit

Hello I am trying to setup email notifications for push to gerrit . 
I am receiving emails when I push to `HEAD:refs/for/master` or the `review branch` on gerrit

Ex:- `git push gerrit HEAD:refs/for/master` Triggers email notifications based on settings in `Watch Projects` under `Settings` in Gerrit webpage.

But , when I do push to master -

`git push gerrit master` email notifications are not being triggered .

Can anyone please help me setup email notifications for pushes to master branch also on gerrit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Gerrit documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-notify.html):

> Gerrit can automatically notify users by email when new changes are
> uploaded for review, after comments have been posted on a change, or
> after the change has been submitted to a branch.

So it's not possible to trigger an automatic e-mail notification for changes that have been pushed to a repository without review. However, as described [here](https://review.typo3.org/Documentation/config-hooks.html#_ref_updated), you can use `ref-updated` hook and handle sending e-mails manually:

> **ref-updated**
>
> Called whenever a ref has been updated.
>
> ref-updated --oldrev  --newrev  --refname  --project  --submitter